# TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'tuple' and 'int'

Tags: python, algorithm, typeerror, closest-points

I'm having trouble with dealing with this error unsupported operand type error and I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong in this case. Any help would be appreciated!!

```
def closest_pair(list):
if (len(list) <= 3):
    return min_distance(list)
else:
    left, right = split_into_two(list)
    left_min = closest_pair(left)
    right_min = closest_pair(right)
    if(left_min[2]>right_min[2]):
        return right_min
    else:
        return left_min

def split_into_two(list):
    med_val = statistics.median(list)
    med_x = med_val[0]
    left = []
    right = []
    for i in list:
        if (i[0]<med_x):
            left.append(i)
        else:
            right.append(i)
    return left, right
```

and printing closest_pair gives out:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File, line 109, in <module>
    print(closest_pair(text_file))
  File, line 61, in closest_pair
    left_min = closest_pair(left)
  File, line 62, in closest_pair
    right_min = closest_pair(right)
  File, line 60, in closest_pair
    left, right = split_into_two(list)
  File, line 44, in split_into_two
    med_val = statistics.median(list)
  File, line 358, in median
    return (data[i - 1] + data[i])/2
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'tuple' and 'int'
```

Comment: [`list`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-list) is a bad variable name

Comment: please fix indentation, and provide a [mcve]

Answer (score 2):

The error message is very explicit:

```
    return (data[i - 1] + data[i])/2
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'tuple' and 'int'
```

It says that the program is trying to divide a tuple by an int. So, `data[i - 1] + data[i]` is a tuple, and that means that each of `data[i - 1]` and `data[i]` are tuples and not numbers as you may be expecting.

Note that the error occurs inside the `statistics.median` function. Check that you are passing arguments with the right type to this function.